# The Interleaved Transition System for 2 Independent and Concurrent Transition Systems

Tags: model-checking, software-verification, transition-systems

This question is about **Model Checking** for **Software Formal Verification**
How do you model the joint behavior of 2 *independent* and *concurrent* transition systems?

Specifically, given the two independent and concurrent Transition Systems below; **TS1** and **TS2** (left to right).
[image: Left:TS1 Right:TS2]

A tutor proposed that the resulting Interleaving Transition System **ITS** is 
[image]

I understand how all the shown states and transitions of this **ITS** were gotten, however, why is there no transition from state `(l1,q1)` to `(l3,q2)`--as would be expected if both **TS1** and **TS2** transitioned on action `a`?

Comment: The definition of the interleaving operator (as opposed to e.g. the interface parallel operator in CSP) is that each component can take $a$- or $b$-transitions on its own - there is no synchronization.

Comment: @KlausDraeger, thanks for your reply; I think I get it now: _the interleaving operator is not synchronized by definition_. In that case, can we say that the interleaving operator does not model the **joint behavior** of the two systems--since it does not account for synchronization?

Comment: Only if you assume that systems are supposed to synchronize on all shared symbols. The point of having interleaving (and, as in CSP, parametrizing the parallel composition operator with a set of symbols on which to synchronize) is to allow you to represent a greater variety of models of interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the interleaving operator is not synchronized, so any transition in $TS1\ |||\ TS2$ corresponds to a transition in a single component while the other one remains in whatever state it is.

More generally, in process algebras like CSP, the parallel composition operator $||$ can be parameterized with a set of symbols on which to synchronize - for example, you could consider $TS1\ |[\{a\}]|\ TS2$, which has the same states and $b$-transitions as $TS1\ |||\ TS2$, but only two (synchronized) $a$-transitions $(l_1,q_1)\to(l_3,q_2)$ and $(l_2,q_1)\to(l_1,q_2)$. In particular, $|||$ is the special case $|[\emptyset]|$.

The point is that (together with additional operations like hiding) this allows you to represent a far greater variety of models of interaction.